# Initialization error with CDYelpFusionKit

Tags: ios, swift, yelp

Trying to use the [CDYelpFusionKit](https://github.com/chrisdhaan/CDYelpFusionKit) api for an app, and I'm getting an error on the first step:

```
 let yelpAPIClient = CDYelpAPIClient(apiKey: "myapikeyhere")
```

It's saying that it's an

> Use of unresolved identifier 'CDYelpAPIClient'

but I have already installed the dependencies with cocoapods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to import the framework

```
import CDYelpFusionKit
```

Comment: I could have sworn I got a module error last time I tried that, but it works. Thanks. I feel like a goof now lmao